# how to validate a .dxf file before uploading it using http://www.woutware.com?

Tags: asp.net, cad

How can i apply the following validation for a .dxf file using Cad lib library (http://www.woutware.com).

I want to upload a .dxf file, and want to apply the following checks before uploading it.

- The program I can use with my laser machines need a .dxf of AutoCAD 2000 version;
- The drawing must be included in a rectangle of 1000x700 units because the program interprets the units as millimeters;
- No blocks or AES objects accepted;
- The default Layer 0 is used for cutting and up to 7 layers for engraving (max 8 layers)
- All objects should be 2D, no 3D objects allowed (most of all the SPLines)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post your question on the [Wout Ware forum](http://www.woutware.com/forum). Most of the checks are fairly easy to do, except checking for 3D objects is probably quite a bit of work because you would need to do some checking for every type of entity.

- The version can be verified using DxfModel.Header.AcadVersion.
- The rectangle is tricky, because there are many ways to draw a rectangle. There could be an LWPOLYLINE, a 2D POLYLINE, a 3D POLYLINE (but without z-coordinate), a collection of 4 LINEs, and there are even other ways to make a rectangle.
- Blocks can be found in DxfModel.Blocks, although I would say that the presence if INSERTs is really important in DxfModel.Entities. AES objects are not supported by CadLib, but you can check if they are present in the original drawing nevertheless by inspecting DxfModel.UnsupportedObjects.
- 3D object checking requires some special check for each entity. Implement an IEntityVisitor object for this, and loop over all entities. A rough check would be if the z-axis of each entity is (0, 0, 1), and the thickness is zero (for entities that have thickness).